# AutoIt find Largest Array Bound between n*.6<=n<=n*1.4

Tags: arrays, math, logic, autoit

Need some help on this from someone smart...lol.

So as the title basically says. Im using autoit developing a script. I want to loop through some numbers and put them in an array. I then want to find the bound with the most amount of numbers in it that match my criteria, which happens to be +/- 50% of the current value

So my thought was after i have the array, and then i sort it, for example.

array = [2,3,4,5,30,43,44,44,44,45,200,600]

this is the part where im stuck-
I then would loop through each number and create an acceptable range for a bound which is +/-50% of the current number. so for this example the largest bound would include the numbers:
 [30,43,44,44,44,45]

My intention after this is to then take the average of these numbers to get a more accurate estimation of the average most common numbers in an array.

My question is how would you do this

Comment: To clarify: you're looking for `number` so that the range `.5*number` to `1.5*number` contains the largest possible number of entries?  And your title was using 40% instead of 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look whether this gets you started.

```
#Include <Array.au3>
; Bound and Average
Global $number_A[12] = [2, 3, 4, 29, 30, 43, 44, 44, 44, 45, 200, 600] ;sorted!

$re = _getBound($number_A)

;~ _ArrayDisplay($re)

Func _getBound($number_A)
    Local $bound_A[UBound($number_A)][3]
    Local $count = 0
    Local $average = 0
    Local $sum = 0
    Local $bound = ''

    For $i = 0 To UBound($number_A) - 1
        $bound_A[$i][0] = $number_A[$i]
        $bound_A[$i][2] = $i
        $count = 0
        For $y = $i + 1 To UBound($number_A) - 1
;~          ConsoleWrite($number_A[$y] & ' <=  ' & $number_A[$i] + $number_A[$i] * 0.5 & @CRLF)
            If $number_A[$y] <= ($number_A[$i] + ($number_A[$i] / 2)) Then $count +=1
        Next
        $bound_A[$i][1] = $count
    Next
    _ArraySort($bound_A, 1, 0, 0, 1)

    For $i = $bound_A[0][2] To $bound_A[0][2]+$bound_A[0][1]
        $bound &= $number_A[$i] & ', '
        $sum += $number_A[$i]
    Next

    $average = $sum / $bound_A[0][1]+1

    ConsoleWrite('The average of ' & $bound & ' (sum= ' & $sum & ') is = ' & $average & @CRLF)

    Return $bound_A
EndFunc   ;==>_getBound
```

Comment: You rock! it is almost how i want it. yes a very good start. i understand all of it except. 
   'For $i = $bound_A[0][2] To $bound_A[0][2]+$bound_A[0][1]
        $bound &= $number_A[$i] & ', '
        $sum += $number_A[$i]
    Next'
Would you mind explaining how this works?

Comment: nevermind i got it, it starts at the index of the start of the bound and increments by how large that bound is.

Comment: Yes, you got it! Glad, I could help. Cu